# Function doesn't continue after toArray() callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to get data from my MongoDB database and return a new id for user creation through a function called create_user_id.
I noticed the function returns `undefined` even though `newID`'s value is numeric.
Any idea why the function stops after the callback function of `.toArray()`?

```
const create_user_id = () => {
  let maxID = -1;
  let newID;
  users.find({}).toArray((err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
    else {
      results.forEach((item) => {
        if (item.id != null) {
          console.log("max id:", maxID)
          if (item.id > maxID) {
            maxID = item.id

          }
        }
      })
      newID = maxID + 1;
    }
  })
  console.log("doesnt reach this line", newID)
  return newID;
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the terminal?

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Nope